# With htaccess using first level folder name only to id file name, variable

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I would like to break the the first level folder name into parts that would identify the file name to call and the varialbe to pass. Specifically, the first character would be the file name without the .php at the end, and the rest would be a variable that is passed.

Examples:

http://example.com/avarvalue => http://example.com/a.php?var=varvalue

http://example.com/d4312 => http://example.com/d.php?var=4312

http://example.com/yblue => http://example.com/y.php?var=blue

http://example.com/7786yu => http://example.com/7.php?var=786yu

How can this be done, if at all?

Comment: Thank you for posting to StackOverflow. Please provide the code that you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z])([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?var=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: I tried. It would not allow me to do so with my beginner's reputation. I'll come back to this when my reputation bumps. In the interim, can other users reading this help by marking this as useful?

Comment: Reputations are required for upvoting but for accepting the answer you don't need it. If you click the link I have on previous comment then it will show how to mark answer accepted.

Comment: Done! Didn't know... Thank you again.